# .htaccess rewrite with HTTP_HOST and QUERY_STRING

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to set up a redirect to a new host with query string. I am struggling to get the query added to the end of the target url. Here is my example old url

`http://sub.oldexample.com/folder1/page1?value=ABC123`

I would like it to go to

`http://newexample.com/folder3/page6?value=ABC123`

I do not have a problem when a `query` is not involved, for example the following code works perfectly but is unsuitable

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.oldexample.com$ 
RewriteRule ^folder1/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9])$ http://newexample.com/folder3/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I have tried to include a `query` condition but it fails

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(value=ABC123)
RewriteRule ^$ http://newexample.com/folder3/page6?%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I find the following link a perfect environment for testing a `.htaccess` rule as it gives the output url that is generated

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: have you tried `(.*0)` insteasd of `ABS123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.oldexample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)value=ABC123(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder1/page1/?$ http://newexample.com/folder3/page6 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You don't need to copy `QUERY_STRING` as it will be automatically carried over to new URL.

Comment: Thanks, it redirects but doeas not add the query to the end? The output is `http://newexample.com/folder3/page6` as can be checked here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: That site is not very reliable for testing .htaccess actually. Try it out on your server and use a different browser to test.

Comment: Also remember to keep this rule on top of your all other rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out tomorrow when I have access to the server again, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/?folder1/page1$ http://newexample.com/folder3/page6 [QSA,R=301]
```

Just try to use the `[QSA]` flag.